# Finding the td associated to its table onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like below

```
<table onclick="dosomething()">
<tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
</table>
```

After I click on the table, I need to find the td on which the click happened. I cannot have onclick event written on tr or td.

Comment: I think the event will only register as originating from the table.

Comment: You can use `event.target`, but you should not use inline handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#tbl").bind("click", function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName == "TD"){
            //do your magic
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (give your `table` a class of `myClass`- or whatever you want):

```
function tableClicked(td) {
    // Do something dependent on the td which was clicked
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table.myClass td").click(function () {
        tableClicked(this);
    });
});
```

This means that you don't have to add `onclick` attributes to the `<td>` tags.

Comment: Well, he's still adding them... (just not manually in the markup!)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're not adding any `onclick` attributes this way.

Answer (score 1):

Add an Id to the table and remove onClick handler. this is to seperate the behavior and content.

```
<table id="tableId">
```

since event will bubble up, capture it on table element and find the target, so you don't need to add event listener to every td.

```
$('#tableId').click(function(e){
     //the td is the target where event happens
     var td=e.target;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would dump the onclick and do this

```
$("#myTable td").click(function() {
   $(this).html();    // get the value
   $(this).hide();    // hide it
   $(this).remove();  // remove it
});
```

```
<table id="myTable">
   <tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
   <tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
   <tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
</table>
```